# Using hCaptcha for two button's form

Tags: forms, submit, hcaptcha

I have an issue regarding hCaptcha. I'm trying to set it on a form with two buttons firing two different actions.

Problem is, when I solve the second button it works, but when I solve the first one it doesn't, sends me a missing-input-response error.

So I understand that hCaptcha is looking for key/value pairs in the form, and the second button is overwriting the first one, so that when I solve the first the token isn't stored and therefore not handled to back end.

Here's a code sample :

```
<?php
$captcha = 0;
if(isset($_POST['h-captcha-response']))
{
$data = array(
            'secret' => "my_secret",
            'response' => $_POST['h-captcha-response']
        );
$verify = curl_init();
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://hcaptcha.com/siteverify");
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($verify);
var_dump($response);
$responseData = json_decode($response);
if($responseData->success)
$captcha = 1;
}
else
$captcha = 1;
if($captcha == 1)
{
?>
<html>
  <head>
 
      </head>
  <body>
    <form action="#" method=POST id="form_">
      <textarea name=input_ rows="1" cols="40" id="input"></textarea><br/>
      <input type=submit name=perform1 value=perform1 id="submit1" class="h-captcha" data-sitekey="mykey" data-callback="onSubmit"/>
     <input type=submit name=perform2 value=perform2 id="submit2" class="h-captcha" data-sitekey="mykey" data-callback="onSubmit"/>
      <br/>
      </form>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        function onSubmit(token) {
          document.getElementById('form_').submit();
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

I tried various things, such as store the token in hidden input but it didn't work.
Seems odd that it cannot handle two submit buttons. I know reCaptcha has the same issue but I found some solutions online for it. Here I cannot find anything.

If you have any idea of a solution.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old topic but I got on same issue. One of the solution is to put one submit per form and therefore one captcha and you can get the corresponding one without any issues.

Second possibility is to `hcaptcha.execute()` on form submit and stick on one captcha. And remove the h-captcha class from input buttons.